# Styles not being applied to multisite setup

Tags: multisite

I have set up my first multi-site website and it is great however I'm having issues updating my style sheet for my websites. My multisite is set up as a subdomain install. I have my [main site here,](http://www.meltmineralspa.com/) and the [subdomain here](http://naramata.meltmineralspa.com/).

Currently, I have two sites on my network using two different themes. I am attempting to update some styles in my main website theme folder (backend-files/themes/simply-pro/style.css) where backend files were renamed from wp-content. ((EDIT: I use a plugin called iThemes Security and it allows me to rename my wp-content folder. So I was just stating that my folder is a bit different but acts the same. I am putting my styles in my child theme but they are not being applied at all.))

However, no styles are being applied. I am not using a caching plugin and I have checked my changes out in the Google Chrome incognito window. When I view the source I can see my main site is grabbing the right stylesheet but the changes aren't there.

I have checked many articles online but none are what I am looking for. Here are a few articles I have tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061262/wordpress-multisite-child-theme-not-working
http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/08/19/common-wordpress-multisite-problems-and-solutions/

and a few more as I've been looking for an answer or some help online for the last couple hours now. I even came across this great article about setting up a multisite install but it doesnt mention anything about styling the sites - https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-complete-guide-to-creating-a-wordpress-multisite-installation.

Is there something I need to additionally add to my .htaccess file, or add to my wp-config to get my style changes working with multisite?

Comment: what does this mean:  **my main website theme folder (backend-files/themes/simply-pro/style.css) where backend-files was renamed from wp-content** ?  If you are putting css files in some other directory, your theme will not find them unless you create a child version of the theme and enqueue the css yourself.

Comment: @CC Sorry i didn't see this until now. I use a plugin called iThemes Security and it allows me to rename my wp-content folder. So I was just stating that my folder is a bit different but acts the same. I am putting my styles in my child theme but they are not being applied at all. I'm thinking I need to add something to my .htaccess file to tell wordpress these styles are for website #1 but haven't found anything helpful for me yet.